# Can I use T4 template features to generate C# classes from javascript class definitions?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, code-generation, t4

I have a javascript based library and would like to generate some C# classes for it.  Unfortunately, I do not know T4 at all, so I may not have included information you need to answer this question.  please comment, and I will edit as needed.

Thanks!

Comment: But what those generated classes supposed to do? Will they have the logic of JavaScript classes or they will act as some sort of proxy classes?

Comment: they will assist me in writing classes that standardize the jqgrid definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with T4 templates you can generate pretty much anything.

But you'll need to parse those JavaScript files somehow by yourself within T4.

Comment: It may be easer parsing some json (if you can easily get that some how) and then generate a C# class from that

Answer (score 1):

Three Routes to try in order of niceness

a) Use CodeModel in Visual Studio 2008 or later to parse the javascript source code
b) Jscript.NET compiler to parse your code / or Eval() objects from it then walk over that code
c) Use RegEx to parse on your own

Please Drop me a line at tfischer AT tangible . DE. I am doing this for C# anyways right now an can add js for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write a T4 template that creates C# classes from JavaScript class definitions. But there is nothing in T4 that helps you with doing so. A T4 template is essentially just a C# script that is executed by Visual Studio whenever the template file is modified.

Comment: what do you mean by "there is nothing in T4" that helps you with doing so?  Regent, above suggested that "you'll need to parse those Javascript files somehow by yourself"-- which seems to me to be a pretty lousy experience.

Comment: @MedicineMan: as dtb said, there is little what Visual Studio and .NET Framework can help you with to transform JavaScript class definitions out of the box.